# Rule FusionActive Template Library (ATL) failed during SQL Server 2008 R2 Installation

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Created an Azure VM running Windows 2008 R2 Datacentre. Sometime in the past I installed SQL 2008 Express R2. After it worked for sometime today MS SQL SERVER service failed to start with the following message:

> Activation context generation failed for c:\program files\microsoft security client\MSESysprep.dll.Error in manifest or policy file c:\program files\microsoft security client\MSESysprep.dll on line 10. The element imaging appears as a child of element urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1 assembly which is not supported by this version of Windows.

I uninstalled SQL Express and attempted a reinstall only to find this error:

> Rule “FusionActive Template Library (ATL)” failed at SQL Server 2008 R2 Installation

Both errors appeared to be related to a manifest corruption. After sometime I found the following resolved my problem.

If you have another working installation, you can copy the following two manifest files from the working server to the failing server:

> > C:\Windows\winsxs\Manifests\amd64_microsoft.vc80.atl_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.4053_none_8a1a02152edb659b.manifest
> >
> > C:\Windows\winsxs\Manifests\x86_microsoft.vc80.atl_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.4053_none_d1c738ec43578ea1.manifest

If you don’t have another working installation, find and open the files mentioned above and paste the following xml in them:

AMD64 Manifest:  (see link)

X86 Manifest: (see link)

Note: You probably need to change the permissions for those files to be able to overwrite them. To do so, go to the file properties, Security tab, Advanced, Owner tab, Edit, Select the Administrators group and click three times OK until all windows are closed. 
Reopen the properties for the file, Security tab, Edit, Select the Administrators group and select Full Control.

In a nutshell i simply copied the AMD64 Manifest into C:\Windows\winsxs\Manifests\amd64_microsoft.vc80.atl_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.4053_none_8a1a02152edb659b.manifest which was empty and the issue was resolved.

Hope this helps someone.

REF
http://blog.codit.eu/post/2013/02/06/Rule-%E2%80%9CFusionActive-Template-Library-(ATL)%E2%80%9D-failed-at-SQL-Server-2008-R2-Installation.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Nutshell**

Copied the AMD64 Manifest into

> C:\Windows\winsxs\Manifests\amd64_microsoft.vc80.atl_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.
>   4053_none_8a1a02152edb659b.manifest

Which was empty and the issue was resolved.

**Resolution**

When trying to install SQL Server 2008 R2 on a Windows Server 2008 R2 Virtual Machine on Azure, you might come across the following error at the Setup Support Rules step. This has to do with two manifest files that are corrupt.

If you have another working installation, you can copy the following two manifest files from the working server to the failing server:

- C:\Windows\winsxs\Manifests\amd64_microsoft.vc80.atl_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.4053_none_8a1a02152edb659b.manifest
- C:\Windows\winsxs\Manifests\x86_microsoft.vc80.atl_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.4053_none_d1c738ec43578ea1.manifest

If you don’t have another working installation, find and open the files mentioned above and paste the following xml in them:

AMD64 Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> 
<!-- Copyright © 1981-2001 Microsoft Corporation --> 
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0"> 
<noInheritable/> 
<assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.VC80.ATL"     
version="8.0.50727.4053" processorArchitecture="amd64" 
publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b"/> 
<file name="ATL80.dll" hash="99840dcc34e78af239d80841eba316c184e407cd"     
hashalg="SHA1"/> 
</assembly>
X86 Manifest: 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> 
<!-- Copyright © 1981-2001 Microsoft Corporation –> 
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0"> 
<noInheritable/> 
<assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.VC80.ATL" 
version="8.0.50727.4053" processorArchitecture="x86" 
publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b"/> 
<file name="ATL80.dll" hash="6d7ce37b5753aa3f8b6c2c8170011b000bbed2e9" 
hashalg="SHA1"/> 
</assembly>
```

Note: You probably need to change the permissions for those files to be able to overwrite them.

To do so:

- go to the file properties
- Security tab
- Advanced
- Owner tab
- Edit
- Select the Administrators group
- and click three times OK until all windows are closed.
- Reopen the properties for the file
- Security tab
- Edit
- Select the Administrators group
- and select Full Control.

**Ref**

http://blog.codit.eu/post/2013/02/06/Rule-%E2%80%9CFusionActive-Template-Library-(ATL)%E2%80%9D-failed-at-SQL-Server-2008-R2-Installation.aspx

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer did not work for me, but this suggestion did:  manually install the Sql Server 2015 Setup Files (see http://blog.amastaneh.com/2012/11/fusion-active-template-library-atl.html)

Comment: Link seems dead. For future generations - go to installation media, then go to \1033_ENU_LP\{platform}\Setup\sqlsupport_msi and install SqlSupport.msi.